# Missing Render Passes in Blender 2.8+

Tags: rendering, uv, render-passes

I can't find the UV render pass in the new Blender UI. In fact, a lot of passes seem gone. Is there any hidden way of enabling it? What's the easier way of reproducing this effect? (I haven't used Blender in several years)

[image: gone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select Cycles render under render properties >>> Render Engine >> Cycles

[image]